# Wp set post terms not work

Tags: terms

My code is not working, it does not add the taxonomy

```
add_action('init', 'post_test', 10);
function post_test() {
    $empty = get_page_by_title('Produto teste', OBJECT, 'produtos');
    if(empty($empty)) {
        $insert_post = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'produtos',
            'post_title' => 'Produto teste',
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($insert_post);
        if ($post_id) {
            wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array('metais'), 'categoria-produtos'); // tag metais id is 108
        }
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'fornecedores', '5948'); // id do fornecedor
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_fornecedores', 'field_52377232eb265');
    }
}
```

why not work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As stated in the [`wp_set_post_terms` Comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/#comment-1117):

> This function will only work on the native post type. For a taxonomy on a custom post type use wp_set_object_terms()

[`wp_set_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/)

Comment: Thanks brother, tihis code woks! : `wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array('metais'), 'categoria-produtos', true); // tag metais id is 108` thnks thnks

Comment: This is not the case any more. For WP 5+ you can use both even for custom post types.

Comment: Now the Codex says : `This function will work on any post type. Alternatively, wp_set_object_terms() can be used.`

Comment: @ToleaBivol Cannot confirm that, lost 4 hours searching why custom taxonomy was not set, found out it's because there's a different between wp_set_post_terms and wp_set_object_terms

Comment: Classic Wordpress quality code.